# Using Webpack to bundle node_modules and client side js with express

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I'm relatively new to webpack and a bit confused about how to set it up, I'm using express as a web server and most of my code is server-side code.

First I tried something like this by reading through the docs:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/assets",
  target: 'node',
  entry: "../app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }
};
```

This gave me the undesired result of generating a bundle.js with all of the dependencies with all of the server side code for the entire project.

Lets say I have 4 pages.

1. page1 (uses jquery.js, script1.js)
2. page2 (uses jquery.js)
3. page3 (uses jquery.js, script1.js)
4. page4 (does not use js)

I would like to create a webpack that compiles all of these to serve to the client via a webpage. I have installed jquery via `npm install jquery` meaning it is in my `node_modules` directory. `script1.js` is a script file made for the project and stored in a `/assets/js` directory.

How would you do something like this?

Comment: Browsers cache javascript resources (depending on cache headers) so, a user navigating from page1 to page2 doesn't necessarily loads "jquery.js" twice.. as jquery is already loaded and cached.. A general pattern in the wild is to combine all 3rd party libraries in 1 "vendor.js" file and everything else in "app.js"

Comment: This seems rather wasteful because if I was using 3 libraries and compiled them to vendor.js and then went to page4, page 4 would load all 3 libraries but it doesn't use any of them. Bundling app.js also ends up bundling all of my server side code rather than the client side code, I don't have a single entry point for the client side code.

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding @Varinder as the scripts are being loaded once on the initial load and not served again unless you are navigating by entering the address manually in which it loads every time which is the case for you. Webpack is more of  a front end (client) builder. You can use it as a development server and proxy the express app but you shouldn't be building from the server code at all. If you want to load each page with it's own bundle then you would likely need multiple configurations for webpack but you need to define where your client side code is first.

Comment: Which is what I'm asking how to do, since I can't find any examples of building a node module as a dependency, I could give an absolute path to what I think is the entry point for that module, but that seems rather messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after messing around with this for a few hours you can reference node modules by their name, the following will bundle the jquery node module to the file jquery.js in the root project directory.

```
  module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: {
     jquery: "jquery"
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
    }
  };
```